# How to validate Cognito Form using existing data on another application

Tags: cognito-forms

I am very much interested in using Cognito Forms for our school application process. However, we would like to incorporate a validation, which can pick an existing parent, whose ward/wards have been admitted in the school already.

Our school management application has a list of all the parents. How can we build this validation on Cognito Forms?

Comment: I closed this question as it looks like a support ticket, not as a practical, detailed question. See [tour], [ask], [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4502/88163)

Answer (score 0):

We are working on adding support for [Dynamic Webhooks](https://trello.com/c/sgDIKA7o) to [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).  This would enable integration with your SIS but would require a bit of development on your end to create the webhooks.